# how to find language of the current session when calling odata service without passing any language

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We have a use case where we integrate with S4HANA Odata service using a technical user
We do not specify language anywhere while calling the service

The service returns response where some elements of response are language dependent (e.g. units)
we need to know which language was determined at S4HANA side and used for returning the elements based
on the language.

How can we identify the language of the response in cloud SDK>
Regards,
Apoorv

Comment: Could you please expand your question to cover: Is there a reason you don't pro-actively set the language (via the locale setting)? Are you running your application on Cloud Foundry or another environment? Which OData service are you using?

Comment: And also how do you authenticate your user on the S/4HANA system?

Comment: I would agree with @MatKuhr. Setting the language pro-actively would be an easier solution. Just add `sap-language` as header to the OData request. To your original question: I'm not aware of any technical solution to get multi-language responses for a single request.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is generally not possible to obtain the language of an S/4HANA OData service via an OData request. I recommend setting the `sap-language` header proactively.

There might be other means of getting the S/4HANA language set for a specific user that I am not aware of. But unless an OData service implements an endpoint for specifically the user language I believe it cannot be retrieved as part of the OData response.